# how to call a non static method from a static method?

Tags: java, android, methods, static

how to call a non static methode from a BroadcastReceiver class?

OR

how to call a non static method from a static method?

```
public static void startonlylocationmethod (long iden)
{
    onlylocation(iden); //dosen't let me
}

public void onlylocation (long id)
{

}
```

P.S
If I create an object and then using it for calling the method the application crashes

Comment: Think about it: This doesn't make sense. The static method is a *class* method, which is stateless; the non-static method is an *instance* method, which depends on a concrete object instance. *Which* instance is the static method supposed to refer to?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create instance of the class in which the non static method is defined as member method

Comment: If I create an object and then using it for calling the method the application courses

Comment: What do you mean by crash ? exception/error please post the message

Comment: there is no message. it's android it just crashes. "we are sory... bla bla bla"

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. make `onlylocation` static.
2. create an instance of the class you are in and call `onlylocation` on that instance.

Comment: I can't the objects that are inside the method are static

Comment: I mean that if your "onlylocation" method is inside class "A", you need to create A a = new A(); a.onlylocation(iden);

Answer (score 0):

You need do something like this:

```
class A{

static A a = new A();
public static void startonlylocationmethod (long iden)
{
    a.onlylocation(iden);
}

public void onlylocation (long id)
{
   ...
}
```

}